# How to use join between two tables correctly in sql I have an exception

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans-7

I've faced a problems with sql queries, and I need your help plz :(.
In my code I want to display the names of students from c#Log when entering the id of this course this is the c#Log table : [HERE](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108513041/Screenshot%20from%202013-06-23%2012:29:47.png) 
and this is the courses table :[HERE](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108513041/Screenshot%20from%202013-06-23%2012:30:05.png)

This is my code :

```
public void searchRows() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException

{   
     String logName=null;
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/psd_DB?"
              + "user=root&password=123");

       Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Enter the course id you want to display its log:");
       courseId=Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());

       PreparedStatement st1 = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(" SELECT * FROM courses WHERE courseId="+courseId);
       ResultSet r=(ResultSet) st1.executeQuery();
       while(r.next())

       {
           logName=r.getString("courseName")+"Log";
       }

       //System.out.println(logName);

       PreparedStatement st2 = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("SELECT "+logName+"."+"studentName FROM "+logName+" INNER JOIN courses ON "+logName+"."+courseId+"="+"courses."+courseId+";");
       st2.executeQuery();

}
```

when I've entered 2 , the output is this exception :

*Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'C' in 'field list'*

Comment: It's not a join problem, _Unknown column 'C' in 'field list'_ means that you are trying to access a field that doesn't exist, check your field names.

Comment: I wrote this :("SELECT "+logName+"."+"studentName FROM "+logName+" INNER JOIN courses ON "+logName+"."+courseId+"="+"courses."+courseId+";")

Comment: I don't know why I got this exception ???

Comment: because one of your variables is identifying a column that doesn't exist, check your variables value, the one that is `C` is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you are using `PreparedStatement` but still you code is vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Do it like this:

```
courseId=Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());

PreparedStatement st1 = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("   
   SELECT * FROM courses WHERE courseId=?");

st1.setInt(1,courseId);
ResultSet r = st1.executeQuery();
```

Also the exception is quite self-explanatory :

Unknown column `C` meaning you are trying to select a column from your table that does not exist, so better check if you are accessing correct columns.

A workaround :  print the sql queries before executing them so that you know which query is getting executed (you can remove this print statements after once you get your expected results).

Answer (score 0):

The join is not the immediate problem - you are specifying an unknown column in the sql statement.

Try using a debugger to see the contents of the SQL statements, or simply output them to the console and try running them manually against your database